# How to Hide Images in Google Spreadsheets with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a dashboard in Google Spreadsheets and want to include some images to be shown when certain rows are hidden/shown. Is this possible? I've used insertImage to insert the image but I can't find a way to delete or hide the image (hiding the rows does not affect images).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an UI ? If so, are you using UIApp ? Can you post some code, please. Code speaks louder than words. 
In general, if you have the image on a panel, you can hide the panel

Comment: No I'm not (still new to GAS). I'm just using the following code inside a function that hides rows (can't work out how to format as code, sorry!):

ss.insertImage("https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1dU0CFHYoGpv-cOWPW5V7ApFNg0JfiwB1ZACrU4EvMqo/pub?w=100&h=100", colIndex, rowIndex-1);

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way of removing an image from the Apps Script API. Even if you delete a row, the image will still remain.

You should raise a request for this feature in the Issue Tracker ( http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list ) .

EDIT:
Looks like there is already a very old issue for this https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=64 . Along with a workaround mentioned there

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you directly use the spreadsheet native function =Image(URL,section), it will be show or hide with the cells