# Google Sheets Hide Images When Hiding Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have been trying to figure out a way to hide an image in google sheets when I am hiding rows that include the image.

The image is a button that has a **script** attached to it, which means that I cannot just use the =IMAGE() formula, and cannot use an image inside of a cell either.

The problem is that when I hide rows the image stays. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Hide Images in Google Spreadsheets with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665401/how-to-hide-images-in-google-spreadsheets-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: I have actually already looked at that answer and unfortunately it does not answer my question. The problem with just deleting the button is that I cannot add it back with the script attached once again. The script can only be added manually from what I have found.

Comment: Is the image uploaded from a local machine, or inserted from URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, there is no way of doing this.*

#### More Information:

Images in a Google Sheet that are not inserted using the `=IMAGE()` formula, *nor* by inserting the image directly in a cell, are represented by an `OverGridImage` object in Google Apps Script.

As you can see in the documentation for this class, [***there exists no method which allows you to hide the image, other than deleting it altogether***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image).

The reason that hiding cells/rows/columns does not hide the image either, is because the image is not tied to any indvidual cell, row or column - it is inserted over the grid system of a specific sheet.

#### A Mix of Both Good and Bad News:

Now, *in theory*, what you could do instead, is store the information about the image in the script properties, and then delete/insert the image again when you wish to hide it.

Unfortunately, it appears that the `.getUrl()` method of the aforementioned `OverGridImage` class [is bugged](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122429709) and does not return the URL of the image - this is something that I have checked myself.

In this case, I would suggest going to the issue link for [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122429709) and hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left to let Google know that more people need this to be seen to.

I would also suggest filing a Feature Request with Google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113), detailing that you would like to see the showing and hiding of overlay images implemented in Google Apps Script. The above link is directly for Apps Script feature requests.

**And for future readers:** If you are encountering this, and the `.getUrl()` method has been fixed, then you can use the following functions as a workaround to show and hide images. This uses `PropertiesService` to save the image data into the script's properties, and then uses them to re-insert the image after deletion.

```js
function hideImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var image = ss.getImages(); // assuming this is the only image
  var url = image[0].getUrl();
  var col = image[0].getAnchorCell().getColumn();
  var row = image[0].getAnchorCell().getRow();
  var xOffset = image[0].getAnchorCellXOffset();
  var yOffset = image[0].getAnchorCellYOffset();
  
  var details = [url, col, row, xOffset, yOffset];
  console.log(details);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("image", details.toString());
  image[0].remove();  
}

function showImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var details = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("image").split(",");
     
  // change for your sheet name
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    .insertImage(details[0], details[1], details[2], details[3], details[4])
  
}
```

#### References:

- [Class OverGridImage | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image)
- [OverTheGrid Image getUrl() seems to not working - Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122429709)
- [Google Apps Script Feature Request Form - Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)
- [Class PropertiesService | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [`insertImage(url, column, row, offsetX, offsetY)` - Class Spreadsheet | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row,-offsetx,-offsety)